# Inkscape arrow is only half

Tags: inkscape, arrow

In Inkscape, when the arrow is rotated, the arrow is only half displayed. How can I set it up to keep it unchanged？ Thank you!
[image]

Comment: I can't replicate this problem unfortunately. It could just be a glitch. Does it disappear if you zoom in or out a bit?  Maybe consider sharing the SVG if you want someone to investigate it further.

Comment: Try switching to the outline view (View -> Display Mode -> Outline) – maybe it reveals something hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar problem where arrows weren't displayed fully. I noticed that the plane I drew them was blurred. By setting the blur back to zero, the arrows where drawn correctly.